# How create proper flexbox to make one column inside of content scrollable and another one static?

Tags: css, sass

I want to create a layout where we have a **header** (responsive, with any height), **footer** (responsive, with any height), and **content** that fills the rest of space. *Content* should have **two columns** - first(right) that **fits the content** and second(left) that is very long and should have **overflow** with y-axis scrolling.

Detailed snipped with HTML and CSS attached.

I have problem with making them work inside of flexible height. I know how to make it work when I have only two columns, but with a responsive footer and header, I have problems.

I also have a code snippet inside of [codepen](https://codepen.io/yuriyward/pen/abdRgPv)

> Thanks in advance for any help :)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  color: black;
  border: 5px purple solid;
}

.column-with-overflow {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.column-with-overflow-content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  height: 60px; // assume that It's not known - any height
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px; // assume that It's not known - any height
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box header">Header</div>
    <div class="box content">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class='column column-with-overflow'>
                <div class='column-with-overflow-content'>
                        box 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='column'>box 2</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="box footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed height to your `.box.content` div element.

And use `min-height` in `.column-with-overflow-content` insted of `height`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  color: black;
  border: 5px purple solid;
}

.column-with-overflow {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.column-with-overflow-content {
  min-height: 1000px; /* use min-height */
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.box.content { height: 100px; } /* set height to columns container */

.box {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  height: 60px; // assume that It's not known - any height
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px; // assume that It's not known - any height
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box header">Header</div>
    <div class="box content">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class='column column-with-overflow'>
                <div class='column-with-overflow-content'>
                        box 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='column'>box 2</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="box footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, unfortunately I want to make it flexible - it should be any height. Like content = whole height - (responsive header height + responsive footer height)